# Making the background of Flutter app project to the device's background

Tags: android, flutter, launcher

I am creating a launcher app with Flutter. But i want the launcher's background is match with the device's background. Like in another launchers in Play Store.
How can I do it? Please answer. :)

I tried `Color.transparent` but it is just making the black background.
Then I Googled the my question but i didn't find the answer that I am looking.
That's it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I am googled more and find this:

```
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Link: https://www.androidauthority.com/make-a-custom-android-launcher-837342-837342/

Comment: but this isn't for flutter btw.